# React / Javascript : Why i cannot access the key "target" in the body of an arrow function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, arrow-functions

I am newbie to Javascript / React and i am doing bit of development using React Functional Component. Let start off by showing you the sample code below.

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {

  function handleChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }
  
  return (
    <input name="firstName" onChange={handleChange} />
  );
}

export default App;
```

Now i don't have any issue with the above code. Pretty straight forward. I can access the event.target.value in the function handleChange.

Now what if i change the handleChange function to below.

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {

  handleChange = ({ target: {value}}) => {
    console.log(value); // clause 1 - No issue
    // console.log(target) // clause 2 - Undefined ?
  }
  
  return (
    <input name="firstName" onChange={handleChange} />
  );
}

export default App;
```

If i uncomment clause 2 - results will print undefined. So let me try and understand this first.

> ({ target: {value})

This is a function parameter which has an object as its argument. This object has a property called target with its value called value. That's my understanding. Simple key/value pair. So if that is the case, why can't i access the key property target? Why clause 2 produces undefined?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: It seems like you have a missing bracket there, is it intended? `({ target: {value})` vs `({ target: {value}})`

Comment: @AngYC Tx. Typo error. Fixed that now

Comment: Because that isn't how destructuring works.

Comment: The `target` variable is not defined directly in the argument list. It is only destructured from the argument object into the value variable. Therefore, if you try to log `target` directly, you will get a reference error indicating that `target` is not defined.

Answer (score 3):

> If i uncomment clause 2 - results will print undefined.

If so, then you have an in-scope `target` binding that you haven't shown that contains the value `undefined` (if you didn't, you'd get a `ReferenceError`¹). It has nothing to do with the `target` in your parameter destructuring pattern, though.

When you use nested destructuring like `{target: {value}}` in the parameter list, you're **only** defining the `value` binding, not a `target` binding.

If you want both, just use `{ target }` in the parameter list, then get `value` from it in the function body.

(Either way, be sure to add `const` [or `let`] to declare `handleChange` so you're not relying on what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Variables*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). And you're also missing the `=>` on the arrow function.)

```
const handleChange = ({ target }) => {
    const { value } = target;
    console.log(value);
    console.log(target);
};
```

```js
const {useState} = React;

function App() {

    const handleChange = ({ target }) => {
        const { value } = target;
        console.log(value);
        console.log(target);
    };

    return (
      <input name="firstName" onChange={handleChange} />
    );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Or as Andy points out in a comment, use `{ target, target: { value } }`:

```
const handleChange = ({ target, target: { value } }) => {
    console.log(value);
    console.log(target);
};
```

```js
const {useState} = React;

function App() {

    const handleChange = ({ target, target: { value } }) => {
        console.log(value);
        console.log(target);
    };

    return (
      <input name="firstName" onChange={handleChange} />
    );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

---

¹ If you didn't have that in-scope `target`, you'd get:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: target is not defined

```js
const {useState} = React;

function App() {

  handleChange = ({ target: {value}}) => {
      console.log(value); // clause 1 - No issue
      console.log(target) // clause 2 - Undefined ?
  };
  
  return (
    <input name="firstName" onChange={handleChange} />
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me digest more here .. Appreciate

Comment: @yapkm01 If you wanted to do it in one line you'd want to destructure the `target` out separately; `{ target, target: { value } }`.

Comment: @Andy - I have a bad habit of forgetting you can do that. Nice one!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Is forgetfulness a habit? :)

Comment: @Andy - I don't recall...